# Bibtex saying I am missing a field name in @unpublished

Tags: bibtex

From googling, I have seen that the @unpublished is recommended for random articles found online. The required fields are note, author and title. Why then is the following bib entry giving an error?

```
@unpublished(de_finetti,
author = {Michael Newton},
title = {Genesis of Bayesian Analysis: Exchangeability and de Finetti's Theroem},
note = {Accessed 1-28-14}
}
```

Gives the error

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: biblio.bib
You're missing a field name---line 5 of file biblio.bib
 : 
 : }
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

Comment: Typo: `@unpublished(de_finetti,` should have `{` don't `(`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `(` instead of `{` after `@unpublished`.

---

By the way, you should modify the `title` field:

```
title = {Genesis of {Bayesian} Analysis: Exchangeability and de {Finetti's} Theorem},
```

so that “Bayesian” and “Finetti” can't be lowercased by the bibliography style.

Here's what you get with your entry:

[image]

Here's the modified entry with the result:

```
@unpublished{de_finetti,
author = {Michael Newton},
title = {Genesis of {Bayesian} Analysis: Exchangeability and de {Finetti's} Theorem},
note = {Accessed 1-28-14}
}
```

[image]

You could add a tie: `de~{Finetti's}` but this probably would lead to poor linebreaking.

Comment: Better to write "Genesis of {B}ayesian ...".  Some obscure `.bst`s capitalise the whole title.

Comment: @richard No, it's better `Genesis of {Bayesian}`.

Comment: No, if you do that with a `.bst` that capitalises the title, you end up with something that reads "GENESIS OF Bayesian ANALYSIS: EXCHANGEABILITY AND DE Finetti's THEOREM" which is clearly wrong.  What is the disadvantage to what I wrote?

Comment: @richard Oh, I didn't understand your point. In such a case I'd simply throw away the style. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg When I use `\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}`, each reference line ends with semicolon (`; .`), is it possible to prevent it? I can ask a new question related to this

Comment: @alper That doesn't depend on the document class, but on the bibliography style. Nothing to do with this question. Open a new question *with details*, in particular a short example of a `.bib` file.

Comment: Will do, but looks like it is not a good idea to change bibliography style that a journal provides